# ios: facebook post image on user timeline is post but page time timeline not post

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
[FBRequestConnection
     startWithGraphPath:@"/page-id/photos"
     parameters:dictPost
     HTTPMethod:@"POST"
     completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                         id result,
                         NSError *error)
     {

             fbCompletion(result,error);
     }];
```

The above code working for user timeline post but when i want post created page timeline then not post image .

Comment: why the `if(error)`? I mean, you do the same wether error is set or not...

Comment: error means if not post successfully image then display message "your post not successfully"

Comment: no, if `error` is set, you call `fbCompletion`, and if it is not set, you do the same. No need for the `if`. If something discriminates between `error` and not `error`, it must be inside `fbCompletion` or nowhere at all. So you should simplify the if/else to just `fbCompletion(result,error);`!

Comment: yes you are right. but main issues is not post image on facebook page timeline.

Comment: anyhow, I think if you want your question be answered you'd have to add (at least) 3 additional things to your question: 1) the contents of `dictPost` 2) the code for `fbCompletion` 3) explain how you checked that the image is not posted, i.e. why do you know its not working.